# Formatting Compare-Object output in a non-tech-user-friendly way

Tags: powershell, formatting

Background:
I have two Active Directory groups that control access to a specific service. Membership in either group grants access. Each user that has access uses one license, which is billed to the end customer. Belonging to both groups still only requires one license per user. To better track and account for these licenses, I need to regularly report group membership for these two groups and compare them to get a license count for billing.

Where I started:
Using powershell commands, I can easily compare the two groups and list the output.

```
Compare-Object (Get-ADGroupMember 'group1') (Get-ADGroupMember 'group2') -Property 'Name' -IncludeEqual
```

Compare-Object gives you a list like this:

```
Name                    SideIndicator
----                    -------------
Mary Jones              =>
David Davies            ==
George Jetson           <=
Frank Herbert           <=
Leif Erikson            ==
Chris Columbus          =>
Francis Drake           ==
```

But I'm looking to format it something like this:

```
Name                    Group1     Group2
----                    ------     ------
Mary Jones                           X
David Davies              X          X
George Jetson             X
Frank Herbert             X
Leif Erikson              X          X
Chris Columbus                       X
Francis Drake             X          X
```

It doesn't need to be exactly like that, but I need something a little more readable than ==, =>, and <=.

Suggestions?

Comment: can we see your coding attempts at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table that `Compare-Object` shows in the console isn't its real output, it is just how PowerShell's formatting system automatically displays *objects*, that consist of up to three properties.

By applying some pipelined `|` operations, these objects can be transformed as necessary to produce the desired output.

```sh
Compare-Object (Get-ADGroupMember 'group1') (Get-ADGroupMember 'group2') -Property 'Name' -IncludeEqual |
     ForEach-Object {
         [PSCustomObject] @{
             Name   = $_.Name
             Group1 = if( $_.SideIndicator -in '<=', '==' ) {'x'} else {''}
             Group2 = if( $_.SideIndicator -in '=>', '==' ) {'x'} else {''}

             # Improved syntax for PS 7.x:
             # Group1 = $_.SideIndicator -in '<=', '==' ? 'x' : ''
             # Group2 = $_.SideIndicator -in '=>', '==' ? 'x' : ''
         }
     } |
     Format-Table Name,
                  @{ expression = 'Group1'; align = 'center' },
                  @{ expression = 'Group2'; align = 'center' }
```

**Output:**

```text
Name           Group1 Group2
----           ------ ------
David Davies     x      x
Leif Erikson     x      x
Francis Drake    x      x
Mary Jones              x
Chris Columbus          x
George Jetson    x
Frank Herbert    x
```

<sup>(The order is different due to my sample data, but that shouldn't matter.)</sup>

**Explanations:**

- By piping to `ForEach-Object` we can process each object (row) that is output by `Compare-Object` one-by-one. Within `ForEach-Object`'s script block, the automatic variable `$_` stands for the current object.
- Using `[PSCustomObject] @{ ... }`, we create an anonymous object, that is implicitly output by PowerShell.
- The `Name` property is just copied, obviously.
- Depending on the value of the `SideIndicator` property, we create the values for the `Group1` and `Group2` properties - either an `'x'` or an empty string `''`. It may come as a surprise that you can assign the output of an `if` statement to a property like this. It works like the *ternary operator* in other programming languages. Since [PowerShell 7.x](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) you no longer need this somewhat clumsy construct and can use a real ternary operator, as shown in the commented lines of the code sample.
- Finally, we pipe to `Format-Table` to control the alignment of the `Group1` and `Group2` columns. You can leave out the `Format-Table` call if the default left-alignment is sufficient. The syntax `@{ ... }` in this context defines a *calculated property*. For more information see the `Format-Table` docs for the `-Property` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) and the [About Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) page.

**Bonus code:**

Just for fun, here is another variant to calculate the `Group1` and `Group2` properties. Finding out how it works is left as an exercise for the reader.

```sh
Group1 = $_.SideIndicator -replace '<=|==', 'x' -replace '=>'
Group2 = $_.SideIndicator -replace '=>|==', 'x' -replace '<='
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for explaining that and showing an example of how it works. I was hoping there was a simple formatting switch for the command or something that I was missing in the online help. But nothing's ever that simple, is it? LOL I appreciate the knowledge you've shared. Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again for your assistance. Using your help above, I managed to build a reporting script that shows membership in these groups and spits out a good license report across 30+ customers, breaking it down by customer and group. Using this will save me and our billing people a lot of time. Thanks again.